# Layout is not refreshing the javascript on window resize

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

i am looking to create a design similar to [this](http://goodbysilverstein.com/).

The problem is that when i resize the page in the above reference site in Safari (on iMac and Windows 7), the design is breaking(the images are overlapping etc.)

I tried going through the [js file](http://goodbysilverstein.com/min/g=js) but i couldn't figure out the fix.

Thanks

Comment: I'm really curious how did you go through a minified js file

Comment: @rhgh : i uncompressed the file

Comment: This is most commonly achieved with the masonry plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/.